# How to restrict access to a resource based on frequency of access?

Tags: database, security, access-control, key-management

I want to restrict access to a particular resource based on time (configurable). So suppose user A has time t configured from him. He can access the resource only once every t time units. The values of t can be from a fixed set but not a very small set. I was thinking of using multiple hash chains to encrypt the data, but I am looking for something more scalable.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm interested in your question but you've lost me with the sentence about hash chains.

Comment: just to make it clear I am using multiple hash chains to generate keys that will be used to encrypt data. The data value of the resource keeps changing very frequently. Does that make it clear?